# Reproducir audio al iniciar la aplicación en Android

Tags: android, audio

¿Cuál es la forma correcta de reproducir un audio al iniciar la app?

Eh encontrado esta forma, pero al ejecutar la app, no me muestra ningún error el el `LogCat` pero solo me muestra la pantalla en blanco sin iniciar ninguna actividad. Cabe señalar que eso lo coloco en `onCreate` aún sin poner ningún otro código como para pausarlo o pararlo.

```
mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.menumusic);
        mPlayer.start();
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**NOTA: Si quito las líneas para la reproducción del audio la app se incia correctamente.**

**NOTA2: Tengo creada correctamente la carpeta RAW y el archivo está bien.**

Comment: ¿Estas seguro que el LogCat no muestra nada, tienes activada la opción "Show only selected application"? Aunque seguramente es problema tu emulador, trata de probar con otro! @megaonly

Comment: hola!, estoy completmente seguro, de hecho si lo dejo así sin mas, no crashea ni nada, si quito esas líneas, la app corre sin problemas.

Comment: ¿Tienes un dispositivo real para probar?, generalmente este tipo de pruebas en donde interviene el hardware las realizo en dispositivos reales. @megaonly